# StructureMap recursion using constructor injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I need to figure out how to inject an implementation of an interface into itself. As by the example below where I would like to use the `add` method recursively.

A simple interface with an add function

```
public interface IRecursiveFactory
{
    int Add(int number, int max = 10);
}
```

Injected into the DI container

```
container.For<IRecursiveFactory>().Use<RecursiveFactory>();
```

This would be the obvious implementation **but it is not recursive**

```
public class RecursiveFactory : IRecursiveFactory
{
    public int Add(int number, int max = 10)
    {
        while (number < max)
        {
            number++;
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }

        return number;
    }
}
```

This is a recursive example that won't work, it returns the error `Activation error occurred while trying to get an instance of type IRecursiveFactory`

```
public class RecursiveFactory : IRecursiveFactory
{
    private readonly IRecursiveFactory _recursiveFactory;

    // Inject "self"
    public RecursiveFactory(IRecursiveFactory recursiveFactory)
    {
        _recursiveFactory = recursiveFactory;
    }

    public int Add(int number, int max = 10)
    {
        while (number < max)
        {
            // recurse
            var newNumber = number + 1;
            Console.WriteLine(newNumber);
            number = _recursiveFactory.Add(newNumber);
        }

        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: What requirement do you have that forces you to call `_recursiveFactory.Add` instead of simply calling `this.Add`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Lazy Resolution solves this, other solutions are still interesting since this clearly is an activation issue.

Working version with Lazy

```
public class RecursiveFactory : IRecursiveFactory
{
    private readonly Lazy<IRecursiveFactory> _recursiveFactory;

    public RecursiveFactory(Lazy<IRecursiveFactory> recursiveFactory)
    {
        _recursiveFactory = recursiveFactory;
    }

    public int Add(int number, int max = 10)
    {
        while (number < max)
        {
            var newNumber = number + 1;
            Console.WriteLine(newNumber);
            number = _recursiveFactory.Value.Add(newNumber);
        }

        return number;
    }
}
```